# how to access table row object from an anchor within a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table with a few rows. i want to access the cells with the value that are in the same row as the anchor that triggers the function populateRow();
(i hope i explained it in a clear way).
any idea how to do that?

```
<tr>
   <td>
         some value
   </td>
   <td>
       <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="populateRow();">update</a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
          another value
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="populateRow();">update</a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `populateRow()` function would need to know which anchor was clicked, so you'd need to either pass `this` to it to give it a reference to said anchor:

```
onclick="populateRow(this);"

function populateRow(anchor) {
  var row = $(anchor).closest("tr");
  var firstCellValue = row.find("td").first().text();
}
```

...and from there use `.closest()` to navigate up the DOM to the containing tr element.

Or, better, bind the click event handler with jQuery rather than putting it inline on every row:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#idOfYourTable").on("click", "a", function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var firstCellValue = row.find("td").first().text();
    console.log(firstCellValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="idOfYourTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">update</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 2</td>
    <td>
      <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">update</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

(Click the "Run..." button to see it working.)

Comment: say i have five cells with value and than the anchor how would i access the fifth ?

Comment: Either `row.find("td").eq(4).text()` (note the zero-based index for the `.eq()` method), or `row.find("td:nth-child(5)").text()` (note the one-based index for the `:nth-child()` selector).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is that `populateRow()` function for, but if you want to get value on the first `td` of the same `tr`, then you can try testing this:

> onclick="alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())"

if you want to pass it in `populateRow()` function, you can:

> onclick="populateRow($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text())"

Or ...
It would be more neat if you pass the element then process it later inside your function:

> onclick="populateRow(this)"

```
function populateRow(elm) {
    var val = $(elm).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
    alert(val);
}
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!